# Multiple master views with react-router

Tags: react-router

I can´t get multiple "master" views to work with routes when using react-router. Here is my routes config:

```jsx
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={AppView}>
    <Route path="/log-in" component={LogInView}/>
    <IndexRoute component={MainView}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
      <Route path="company" component={CompanyView} />
      <Route path="clients" component={ClientsView} />
      <Route path="terms-of-service" component={TermsOfServiceView} />
      <Route path="privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicyView} />
      <Route path="contact" component={ContactView} />
    </IndexRoute>
  </Route>
);
```

Any thoughts how I can get this to work?

Comment: `IndexRoute` is a leaf route, you can't nest anything inside it. Check out the auth-flow example in the react router repo. What you want to do is use `onEnter` to check if someone is logged in.

Comment: knowbody oh ok - well besides the log-in page I also want to have other pages, I just removed them from this to illustrate the problem. Do you know if there is any way to make this work? I could use <Route path="/"/> instead of IndexRoute with react-router 0.13

Comment: I definitely encourage you to use 1.0 final as we dropped the support for 0.13.x (there will be no more releases for 0.13.x). Grab me on http://www.reactiflux.com/ I can explain how you can do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah I am using 1.0 and that´s where I ran into problems. Thanks, will contact you there!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to knowbody the solution was quite simple, simply remove the path attribute from the top level Route element and change IndexRoute to a normal Route for the MainView:

```jsx
const routes = (
  <Route component={AppView}>
    <Route path="/log-in" component={LogInView} />
    <Route path="/" component={MainView}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
      <Route path="company" component={CompanyView} />
      <Route path="clients" component={ClientsView} />
      <Route path="terms-of-service" component={TermsOfServiceView} />
      <Route path="privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicyView} />
      <Route path="contact" component={ContactView} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```